# How to find linear transformation with given kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ such that whose kernel is $xy$ plane.

Can you kindly explain it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  How about $f(x,y,z)=(0,0,z)$?

Comment: What part were you struggling with? Is there a particular term you're not sure about, or a step in the process you can't figure out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Your question is equivalent to find a linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^{3} \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that $$\textbf{ker}(T)=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}: z=0, x,y \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$$
where $\textbf{ker}(T)$ is the kernel of the linear transformation $T$.

---

**Solution and detailed explanation:** 
The operative way to find a correspondence rule for a linear transformation subject to certain restrictions is the following:

1. Find a base for the starting vector space, in such a way that it is known how the linear transformation acts on the elements of that chosen base.
2. Verify that the rank-nullity theorem holds.

Now,

1. Wee need to find a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that we know how $T$ acts on these elements. Now, since $\textbf{ker}(T)$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ (vector space starting.)
   I'm sure, you can find since $$\textbf{ker}(T)=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}: z=0, x,y \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$$ so a basis for $\textbf{ker}(T)$ is $$\beta_{\ker(T)}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} \right\} \implies \dim(ker(T))=2.$$
2. Now, we need a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ so, we can choose $$\beta=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \color{blue}{\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}} \right\}$$
   where we can CHOOSE $$T\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \not= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
3. Note that $$T\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad T\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad \text{and} \quad T\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
   then we know how $T$ acts ON the elements of the basis that we select for the starting vector space (domain of $T$).
4. Now, constructing the correspondence rule for $T$ becomes a computational detail problem.
5. Let $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\  c \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ such that $$\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix}=\alpha_{1} \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}+\alpha_{2}\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} +\alpha_{3}\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
   solve it, you can find $\alpha_{1}=a, \alpha_{2}=b, \alpha_{3}=c$, so by property of linearity, "you can apply $T$ to both sides of the equality", then $$T\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix} =aT\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}+b T\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}+ cT\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
   using the hypothesis, you can fint that $$\boxed{T\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ c \end{pmatrix}}$$

also, you can see that $$\dim(ker(T))+\dim(im(T))=\dim(\mathbb{R}^{3})$$ and the kernel of $T$ is the $xy$-plane.

---

**Note:** My intention with this detailed solution is to show future readers on MathSE a general help in solving problems on construction of linear transformation with conditions for construction.

Comment: Yes exactly but I want to know the Maping T such that we got that kernel?

Comment: Ok, I'm writing the complet solution hoping can help you clarify my suggestion.

Comment: @AarifHussain I have written my complete solution, I hope it will be of benefit for your future studies.

Comment: Thank you so much Ramanujan,for your great explaination

Comment: If you explain it will be helpful for every one if image transformation is xy plane  then what will be transformation from R^3 to R^3

Answer (score 0):

The kernel is the set of elements that are sent to zero by the map. Since we are dealing with a linear map, we only need to consider the basis vectors for $\mathbb{R}^3$, namely the set $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$. We want linear combinations of the first two vectors to be sent to 0, so we know that the first two columns of the matrix representation of the linear map should be all zeros. Then, the simplest thing to do to make sure we don't send any *more* elements to zero, just let the last column denote the identity map,  so in the standard representation let the final column be $(0,0,1)^T$.