# $T:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^3$; if $(1,1),(2,3)\in\ker(T)$, is $(\pi,3)\in\ker(T)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am not so familiar with linear algebra, so I would really appreciate your help. I think this is quite a simple question, but I really can't find a way through it.

The proposition I want to prove is as the title says:

> $T:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^3$; if $(1,1),(2,3)\in\ker(T)$, then $(\pi,3)\in\ker(T)$.

Is this proposition right or wrong?

Comment: It is right. Since $(1,1),(2,3)$ are linearly independent, they form a basis of $\Bbb R^2$. Thus every $v\in\Bbb R^2$ can be written as $a(1,1)+b(2,3)$ and $Tv=aT(1,1)+bT(2,3)=0$. Thus kernel is entire $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Please read here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3905157/798113

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $(1,1),(2,3)$ are linearly independent and therefore form a basis of $\mathbb R^2$ as a real vector space (why?).
Also, recall that if $T$ is a linear map, $\ker(T)$ is a linear subspace of the domain of $T$. In this case, what happens if both the vector of a basis of $\mathbb R^2$ are in $\ker(T)$?

Alternatively, you can just consider the second observation ($\ker(T)$ is a vector space); can you write $(\pi,3)$ as a linear combination (with real coefficients) of $(1,1)$ and $(2,3)$, in order to prove that also $(\pi,3)$ lives in $\ker(T)$?